# Haskell: using function value

Tags: haskell

I am writing my first Haskell program and I am having difficulties in making a function use a user-entered input value. I don't yet understand enough about the language, so I started off simply, by creating a function that reads in a user-input value and returns this as an integer. Then, in the main calling function I want to use this value as the input to another function. This is the code scenario:

```
module Main where

square :: Int -> Int
square n = n*n  

getInt :: IO Integer
getInt = do
    putStrLn "Enter a positive integer: "
    s <- getLine
    putStrLn("The number you entered is " ++ s)
    let num = read s :: Integer
    return num

main :: IO ()
main = do 
    num <- getInt
    print num -- works
    print $ square (getInt) -- breaks down here
    print $ square (num) -- also does not work
    print $ square (5) -- works
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Mismatch between `Int` and `Integer`

Let's look at the signatures here:

```
square :: Int -> Int
getInt :: IO Integer
```

It's clear that `Int` is not an `Integer`, so choose either, or use `Num n => n`:

```
square :: Num n => n -> n
getInt :: Num n => IO n
```

### Mismatch between `Int` and `IO Int`

The second problem is a bit more complicated. Since `getInt` is an IO action, it needs to be extracted first to be used:

```
num <- getInt
print $ square num
```

There are other ways to compose a pure function with an IO action:

```
-- Control.Applicative (<$>)
square <$> getInt >>= print

-- Data.Functor (fmap)
fmap square getInt >>= print

-- directly composed with return
getInt >>= return . square >>= print

-- manual lambda extraction
getInt >>= (\x -> return $ square x) >>= print
```

Comment: Actually, none of the last 4 examples type check.

Comment: @chi I wrote that a bit too hastily. Fixed now.

Comment: Also the initial two signatures are not displayed as code (missing indentation). I would write an edit, but spaces do not count as characters apparently (so my edit won't go through).

Answer (score 2):

There are two things going on here.

Firstly, the reason you cannot do `print $ square getInt` is because `getInt` has the type `IO Integer` - you should extract the value via `num <- getInt` first, before running functions that can take and receive `Integer`s.

The second is that you are actually using two different integer types in your program, and Haskell does not automatically coerce between them. Notice that `getInt :: IO Integer` whilst `square :: Int -> Int`. If you were to change the types to be consistent, your line `print $ square num` would work. The `square` function expects an `Int`, whilst you are giving it `num`, which is an `Integer`. The difference between these two types is that `Int` is bounded, as a machine integer, whilst `Integer` is unbounded.